# counting sort - negative integers

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a counting_sort on negative numbers, the following code only seems to work on positive integers. Any pointers on how I can fix it to work on negative numbers?

```
def count_sort(l):
   output = [0] * len(l)
   low = min(l)
   if low >= 0:
      low = 0
   high = max(l)
   working = [0 for i in range(low, high+1)]
   for i in l:
      workng[i] += 1
   for j in range(1, len(working)):
      working[j] += working[j-1]
   for k in reversed(ul):
      output[working[k] - 1] = k
      working[k] -= 1
   return output
```

Comment: Take out the `if low >= 0: low = 0` and see if you can come up with a way to use `low` to change which indexes correspond to which values.

Comment: @Ryan mind explaining some more?

Answer (score 5):

Counting sort can work for any bounded range of integers, they don't all need to be positive. To make your code work for negative values (and work without wasting lots of memory for positive values that are all far from zero, e.g. `[1e10, 1e10+1, 1e10+2]`), just offset your indexes into `count_array` by the minimum value in the input:

```
def counting_sort(unsorted):
   result = [0] * len(unsorted)
   low = min(unsorted)      # we don't care if this is positive or negative any more!
   high = max(unsorted)
   count_array = [0 for i in range(low, high+1)]
   for i in unsorted:
      count_array[i-low] += 1             # use an offset index
   for j in range(1, len(count_array)):
      count_array[j] += count_array[j-1]
   for k in reversed(unsorted):
      result[count_array[k-low] - 1] = k  # here too
      count_array[k-low] -= 1             # and here
   return result
```

Answer (score 0):

When you index `count_array` with negative elements, your algorithm doesn't work. Python will interpret `count_array[-1]` as the last element of `count_array`

So you can either change the code to take that into account or shift all elements before sorting

```
unsorted = [e - low for e in unsorted]
```

and at the end change it back

```
result = [e + low for e in result]
```

Comment: btw this might seem slower than @Blckknght answer, but it's actually faster for a lot of cases. So I'd go with this one cause it improves readability of the algorithm (in my opinion of course)